# Change or replace value in column dataframe by index

Tags: python, pandas

I got some confusion when trying to replace values in the column dataframe.

When I have row 1 and row 2 have the same **Time value** and the same **Variable 1** : add value **Tier A**
When I have row 1 and row 2 have the same **Time value** and the same **Variable 2** : add value **Tier B**

My input:

| Time | Variable 1 | Variable 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | URI |
| 1 | a | CVV |
| 2 | b | URI |
| 2 | c | URI |
| 3 | e | BCN |
| 3 | e | MKL |

Output expected:

| Time | Variable 1 | Variable 2 | Tier |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | URI | A |
| 1 | a | CVV | A |
| 2 | b | URI | B |
| 2 | c | URI | B |
| 3 | e | BCN | A |
| 3 | e | MKL | A |

Hope to have your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to iterate over all rows and compare the values with the previous row. Then we can set both rows to either Tier A or B. The following code is doing exactly this and produces your expected output. The solution of course requires that the dataframe is sorted by the Time column.

```
# Variables for values from the last row
prev_time = -1
prev_variable1 = -1
prev_variable2 = -1

# Iterate over all rows
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    # Extract needed values from row
    time = row[0]
    variable1 = row[1]
    variable2 = row[2]
    
    # Check if current and last row are in Tier A
    if time == prev_time and variable1 == prev_variable1:
        df.at[i-1, 'Tier'] = 'A'
        df.at[i, 'Tier'] = 'A'
        
    # Check if current and last row are in Tier B
    elif time == prev_time and variable2 == prev_variable2:
        df.at[i-1, 'Tier'] = 'B'
        df.at[i, 'Tier'] = 'B'
       
    
    # Set current row values to the previous values of next row
    prev_time = time
    prev_variable1 = variable1
    prev_variable2 = variable2

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Time   Variable 1  Variable 2 Tier
0      1           a         URI    A
1      1           a         CVV    A
2      2           b         URI    B
3      2           c         URI    B
4      3           e         BCN    A
5      3           e         MKL    A
```